# How can I create a column with the "linked to item" option in my custom view?

Tags: list, list-view

I have a custom job that creates a view. In my custom view I want to display the column with the "linked to item type".

Please guide..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you add the FieldRef inside the ViewFields add an Attribute LinkToItem="TRUE"

```
<ViewFields>
 <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
 <FieldRef Name="Filename"/>
 <FieldRef Name="Modified" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
 <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
</ViewFields>
```

If you're creating the view programatically then unfortunately there is no way to set this attribute through the SPViewFieldsCollection returned by SPView.ViewFields.

So you have to:

1. do all of your setup in code
2. call SPView.GetViewXml
3. do string manipulation to add the attribute
4. call SPView.SetViewXml

Comment: Thanks @Per Jakobsen for ur answer. But I am not getting where should I write this code. I am creating the view by C# code. Can you please tell me where should I include this in my code.